# How and how much do fabrication defects affect superconducting qubit coherence time?

Tags: measurement, superconducting-quantum-computing, decoherence, transmon

I used simulations to calculate T1 time of a transmon qubit, but the result is much longer than the lab data. I suspect it was because simulation does not consider fabrication defects. May I ask if there are any useful papers talking about fabrication defects and coherence time? Thank you so much!